# Dynamically add chips to chipgroup

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-chips

I'm trying to add several chips to the chip group dynamically. The first one appears fine but others do not appear properly. But when I do it using XML it works fine.

[image: The last chip added is small, grey, and has no text. It should be orange and contain text like the first three.]

activity_main.xml

```xml
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/chips_select"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.51">
    <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                android:id="@+id/chip_group_main"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                app:chipSpacingHorizontal="4dp">
        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                    style="@style/ChipTextAppearance"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hello"
                    app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:closeIconEnabled="true" />
        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                    style="@style/ChipTextAppearance"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="World"
                    app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:closeIconEnabled="true" />
    </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

In MainActivity.java

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  Chip chip = new Chip(this);
  chip.setText("ABC");
  chip.setChipBackgroundColorResource(R.color.colorAccent);
  chip.setCloseIconVisible(true);
  chip.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
  chip.setTextAppearance(R.style.ChipTextAppearance);

  Chip chip2 = new Chip(this);
  chip.setText("XYZ");
  chip.setChipBackgroundColorResource(R.color.colorAccent);
  chip.setCloseIconVisible(true);
  chip.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
  chip.setTextAppearance(R.style.ChipTextAppearance);

  ChipGroup chipGroup = findViewById(R.id.chip_group_main);

  chipGroup.addView(chip);
  chipGroup.addView(chip2);
}
```

style.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ChipTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Chip">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

standalone_chip.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<chip
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:closeIconEnabled="true"
    style="@style/ChipTextAppearance"
    app:closeIconTint="@android:color/white" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Kotlin :

```
// add chip group dynamically
        item.itemData.projectTags.forEach { tagName ->
            binding.tagChipGroup.addView(createTagChip(context, tagName))
        }
```

// created seaprate method to create chips with attributes.

```
private fun createTagChip(context: Context, chipName: String): Chip {
    return Chip(context).apply {
        text = chipName
        setChipBackgroundColorResource(R.color.purple_500)
        isCloseIconVisible = true
        setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white))
        setTextAppearance(R.style.ChipTextAppearance)
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 26):

In your main activity you are doing like this.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Chip chip = new Chip(this);
        chip.setText("ABC");
        chip.setChipBackgroundColorResource(R.color.colorAccent);
        chip.setCloseIconVisible(true);
        chip.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        chip.setTextAppearance(R.style.ChipTextAppearance);

        Chip chip2 = new Chip(this);
        chip.setText("XYZ");
        chip.setChipBackgroundColorResource(R.color.colorAccent);
        chip.setCloseIconVisible(true);
        chip.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        chip.setTextAppearance(R.style.ChipTextAppearance);


        ChipGroup chipGroup = findViewById(R.id.chip_group_main);

        chipGroup.addView(chip);
        chipGroup.addView(chip2);
```

Notice you are creating a new instance of chip i.e chip2 but you are making changes to chip not chip2 instance in the next lines so the chip2 is not affected with any changes you made before. So in order to fix this change your code like this

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            Chip chip = new Chip(this);
            chip.setText("ABC");
            chip.setChipBackgroundColorResource(R.color.colorAccent);
            chip.setCloseIconVisible(true);
            chip.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            chip.setTextAppearance(R.style.ChipTextAppearance);

            Chip chip2 = new Chip(this);
            chip2.setText("XYZ");  //chip2
            chip2.setChipBackgroundColorResource(R.color.colorAccent);
            chip2.setCloseIconVisible(true);
            chip2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            chip2.setTextAppearance(R.style.ChipTextAppearance);


            ChipGroup chipGroup = findViewById(R.id.chip_group_main);

            chipGroup.addView(chip);
            chipGroup.addView(chip2);
```

Answer (score 10):

yeah, can add chips to group with  `chipGroup.addView(chip);`
please note that you should add id to each chip in order to some functionality of group work perfectly (e.g `singleSelection="true"` )

```
 chip.setId(ViewCompat.generateViewId());
```