# How to add choice chip dynamically in android studio in my case

Tags: java, android, xml, android-chips

##### I have Model Class Like this:

```
private String animalName, type;

public Model(){}

public Model(String animalName, String type){
 this.animalName = animalName;
 this.type = type;
}
//and getter and setters for all vars
```

And `ArrayList<Model>();` according to my model class

so I want to check if my `ArrayList<>()` contains a specific Type ie. **herbivore**
then add those animals according to their type in different ArrayList and I want to make **`CHOICE CHIPS`** according to my type. here is an example of my app:

[image]

##### Note I am using RecyclerView to display Images

**How Can I add That Choice Chips According to my Model Class**
and OnClick on any chips load shows Images according to that.

Any Solution is Appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically add chips to chipgroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61847481/dynamically-add-chips-to-chipgroup)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61847604/9411376 see this may solve your issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Create A Method name it like this or whatever you want

```
private void setChips(String type){
    Chip chip = new Chip(this);
    chip.setText(chipsTitle);
    chip.setCheckable(true);
    //if you not create chipGroup in you xml yet then create it 
    chipGroup.addView(chip);
}
```

And then you can call that method and pass your type for ie - "Herbivores" etc.

```
setChips("Herbivores");
```

And After that you can add ClickListeners to Your chips like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < chipGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
     int finalI = i;
     chipGroup.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Chip chip = chipGroup.findViewById(chipGroupFl.getChildAt(finalI).getId());
            chip.setChecked(true);

            //here you can call your method to load Images
            

        });
    }
```

Comment: yeah! ofCourse Why not!